# Clear data in an array while requesting new json response (fatal error: Index out of range swift 3)

Tags: json, swift

I have json request which show a list of cars. I used timer to refresh the request as well as the list every 10 seconds. The problem is that the data keep adding up to the array and make my application crashes. How can I clear the data before appending new data? What should I do?

```
    let list = listdevices[indexPath.row] // error 

    if list.statusxe == "run" {
        cell?.devnameLabel?.text = list.devname
        cell?.addressLabel?.text = list.address
        cell?.statusxeLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 1/255, green: 117/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)
        cell?.statusxeLabel?.text = "Đang chạy"
        cell?.speedLabel?.text = "\(list.speed) km/h"

    }
   else if  list.statusxe == "stop"{
        cell?.devnameLabel?.text = list.devname
        cell?.addressLabel?.text = list.address
        cell?.statusxeLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 6/255, blue: 6/255, alpha: 1)

        cell?.statusxeLabel?.text = "Đang dừng"
        cell?.speedLabel?.text = ""

    }
    else if list.statusxe == "expired"{
        cell?.devnameLabel?.text = list.devname
        cell?.addressLabel?.text = list.address
        cell?.statusxeLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
        cell?.speedLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black

        cell?.statusxeLabel.text = " "
        cell?.speedLabel?.text = "hết hạn dịch vụ"
    }
    else if list.statusxe == "lost_gprs"{
        cell?.devnameLabel?.text = list.devname
        cell?.addressLabel?.text = list.address
        cell?.statusxeLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
        cell?.statusxeLabel?.text = "Mất GPRS"
        cell?.speedLabel?.text = ""
    }
    cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.disclosureIndicator

    return cell!
}
```

I have json request which show a list of cars. I used timer to refresh the request as well as the list every 10 seconds. The problem is that the data keep adding up to the array and make my application crashes. How can I clear the data before appending new data? What should I do?

```
    let url = "http://api.vnetgps.com:8000/tracking"

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue(token , forHTTPHeaderField: "token")
    request.setValue(username, forHTTPHeaderField: "username")
    request.setValue("-1", forHTTPHeaderField: "devid")
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        if (error != nil ) {
            print("Error")

        }
        else {
            self.listdevices.removeAll()


            if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: Any],

                let items = json?["units"] as? [[String: Any]] {


                for item in items {

                    var lat = item["latitude"] as? String
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(lat, forKey: "latitude")

                    var long = item["longitude"] as? String
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(long, forKey: "longitude")

                   // print("long", long)
                    var devid = item["devid"] as? String
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(devid, forKey: "devid")
                    var devname = item["devname"] as? String
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(devname, forKey: "devname")

                    var speed = item["speed"] as? String
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(speed, forKey: "speed")

                    var statustt = item["status"] as? String
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(statustt, forKey: "statusxe")
                    var drivername = item["drivername"] as? String
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(drivername, forKey: "drivername")
                    var address = item["address"] as? String
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(address, forKey: "address")
                     var direction = item["direction"] as? String


                    self.listdevices.append(Listdevices(statusxe: statustt! , speed: speed!, devid: devid!, devname: devname!, address: address!, latitude: lat!, longitude: long!, drivername: drivername!, direction: direction!))
                    // print("list",self.listdevices)

                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                }


            }
        }

    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Have you initialize array at first before using it ?

Comment: I did var listdevices = [Listdevices]()

Comment: can you show your `numberOfRows` method for tableView?

Comment: override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        
        return self.listdevices.count 
    }

Comment: try with replace the statement `self.listdevices.removeAll()` from else starting to before for loop `(for item in items)`.

Comment: @shahnilay86  still the same

Comment: it still fails I dont know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably that you empty the array while it is being used by the tableview.

Instead use map to replace the old array contents with the new contents. That way you don't need to empty the array first.

Something like:

```
self.listDevices = items.map { Listdevices($0) }
```

And then implement an initialiser for ListDevices like this:

```
init(device: [String: Any]) { ... }
```

A couple of unsolicited code review comments:

- All the writes to UserDefaults are pointless since each iteration just overwrites the previous one, so you should just remove the whole loop.
- Make statusxe into an enum StatusXE
- Replace the long conditional with a switch based on the new StatusXE enum
- Be careful with naming. The variable **list** is not a list, so don't call it that, instead maybe call it **device**. The variable **listdevices** should just be called **devices** or if you insist on using the word list, it should be **deviceList**. Also remember proper camelCasing.
- Avoid force unwrapping. Possibly use the nil coalescing operator to provide default values for device properties that are null.
- Avoid unnecessarily duplicating code. In the long conditional, the first two lines of code are repeated in every case. Just move those two lines out of the conditional.

Comment: do you have Skype. can you help me

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be due to the async nature of your code.
try avoid `self.listdevices.append` and use something like :

```
// declare listdevices with var instead of let
let temp = [Listdevices]()
for item in items {
    ...

    temp.append(Listdevices(statusxe: statustt! , speed: speed!, devid: devid!, devname: devname!, address: address!, latitude: lat!, longitude: long!, drivername: drivername!, direction: direction!))
} 


self.listdevices = temp
```

Comment: I dont run app. error:  cannot assign value of type 'Listdevices' to type '[Listdevices]'

Comment: the ' let temp ' can not be call outside of the loop. if I declare temp outside the loop. Error still there.